# Predictability of predictor variables in regression analysis

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, forecasting, predictive-models

I have run a multiple linear regression analysis to predict the forecast of demand (in litres) of soft drinks. I have 104 sets of weekly data and my independent variables are feature space (measured by the amount of stores in which the product is on the front shelf), temperature, price (per litre), competitor price, competitor feature space, hours of sunlight.

After running the analysis, deeming all relevant variables significant in predicting demand, extracting a predictive equation and testing the model on an out-of-sample data set, the predictive model appears to broadly fit the observed values. However, not all of the above variables are entirely predictable if I am to use this model for future predictions, as even with the out-of-sample data set we were aware of the variable values of each observation - for example, there will be some weeks for which I am not able to predict a value for 'competitor feature space'.

My question is: is there a way of measuring to what degree of accuracy I need to know the inputs of my predictive model in order to yield a usable forecast?

Comment: What is "feature space" and "competitor feature space"? ... By the way, I think what you're looking for is feature selection ... there are several methods to do it ... why don't you first look if your dependent variable is correlated with each dependent variable, may be using Pearson product-moment coefficient ... Look also if you have linear dependent columns, which in linear regression cause what is call the "multicollinearity problem" (you don't want to have correlated features in the dataset) ... PS why did you use the flag "time-series"? ... it doesn't look you're using a time series